# remove disable from input type range jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have 3 radio buttons and a range input type which is disabled, what I want to remove this disable from range type after users clicks a specific radio button from the 3 radio button I tried using removeAttr It doesn't work this is my code for removing the disable attribute
This is code for  radio button

```
<input type="radio" name="restriction" id="rdSelect"  class="cardi" value="cardinality" />
<label for="rdSelect">Caridi</label>
```

And this is code for the input type range

```
<input type="range" name="cardinality" id="cardinality" value="1" min="1" max="100" disabled/>
```

And this is my code for removing disable attribute, but it is not working

```
 $(document).ready(function () {$("#rdSelect").click(function () 
   {
     $("#rag").removeAttr("disabled");
   });
 });
```

Can anyone help me to solve this I really need it, this is two days I couldn't be able to solve it. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to listen to radio button's `change` event. Accordingly, *disbale* or *enable* the slider using *slider widget functions*. E.g. `.slider("enable")` or `.slider("disable")`.

Use *page events* not `.ready()` to add listeners.

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#pageID", function () {
    $("#rdSelect").on("change", function () {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $("#cardinality").slider("enable");
        }
    });
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/2rvk9/)**

Comment: Thank you so much, but one question you are using check box in the demo, I am using radio box and I have 3 radio box now when I am clicking this radio it will enable it for me but when I click other radio buttons it will not disabled again please do you have any Idea?

Comment: @horam create another radio button to disable it http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/NYB5f/

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#rdSelect").click(function(){
     $("#rag").prop("disabled",false);
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Your `range` element has an id `cardinality`, why are you saying `#rag`

Use this to make it enable.

```
$("#cardinality").attr("disabled",false);
```

instead of

```
$("#rag").removeAttr("disabled");
```

Comment: basically `removeAttr` should also work, you have to change `#rag` to `#cardinality`

Answer (score -1):

you may use

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {$("#rdSelect").click(function () {

    $('#cardinality').prop("disabled", false); 
});
});
</script>
<input type="radio" name="restriction" id="rdSelect"  class="cardi" value="cardinality" />
    <label for="rdSelect">Caridi</label> <br/>


    <input type="range" name="cardinality" id="cardinality" value="1" min="1" max="100" disabled=""/>
```

Comment: you put this total code in a html file and test it is working or not.Then you may down vote.One thing,include <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script> on the top.